# Copy range that includes shapes from website to email

Tags: excel, vba

I sent out a daily email. It is mostly a copy paste from a website and worked before.

I now have shapes in the range I want included in the email.

Here is the first part that seems to be fine.

```
Sub Send_EOS()

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next

Set rng = Sheets("Wash").Range("B2:H98").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = Sheets("Settings").Range("E31")
    .CC = Sheets("Settings").Range("E32")
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "" & Sheets("Shift Plan").Range("V3") & " " & Sheets("Shift Plan").Range("V7") & " Shift Wash"
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

This is where the trouble is.

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

I thought `.DrawingObjects.Delete` might be deleting the objects, but removing that didn't fix it.

I also thought `PasteSpecial` might be doing it and so I changed it to paste all but that didn't work.

I also tried not deleting the temp file at the end and not clearing the clipboard to see if something was wrong with the copy, but when I paste it myself the shapes transfer over, but the temp file doesn't show the objects.

I also tried all of these things together with no luck.

Comment: As I'm working through the code, I think it has to have something to do with "Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)" I'm assuming that a TextStream doesn't allow for shapes. So I need to figure out another method of opening the file that allows for shapes and setting "rangetoHTML" to read it.

Comment: Temporarily remove `Kill TempFile`, so you can open the published .htm file from a web browser. Does it contain the shapes?

Comment: Tried that and no dice. I think my observation above is wrong. When I run just the chunk of code pasting into the temporary workbook there is still no shapes. But they are there when I use the same type of special paste. Everything also showed up fine when I changed it to rng.CopyPicture. I ended up giving up and just didn't include shapes in the file.